# Call Yellowfin Business Intelligence services with C#

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wsdl, business-intelligence

I'm trying to use Yellowfin services from my C# code. They are written on Java, so I've [enabed JAX services](http://www.yellowfinbi.com/YFForum-How-to-enable-JAX-web-services-?thread=158117) as they recommend.

So JAX services [are running](http://www.yellowfinbi.com/Image.i4?ImageId=16275) at "localhost:8083/webservices/LegacyReportService?wsdl", and I cannot make them work as [specified](http://wiki.yellowfin.com.au/display/USER71/Report+Service) (I'm running RUNDASHBOARDREPORT method of the ReportService)

That's how I use it:
**Web References** to the YF services running on my localhost:
[image: Web Reference usage screenshot]

Here I **call the service**

```
    public static reportServiceResponse RunDashboardReport(Int32 reportId, Int32 tabId)
    {
        var rq = CreateYfRequest("RUNDASHBOARDREPORT");
        rq.reportId = reportId;
        rq.dashboardTabId = tabId;
        using (var srv = new LegacyReportServiceService())
        {
            var resp = srv.remoteReportCall(rq); // there is no "remoteAdministrationCall" as in the doc
            return resp;
        }
    }


    private static reportServiceRequest CreateYfRequest(String command)
    {
        var rq = new reportServiceRequest
        {
            loginId = "admin@yellowfin.com.au",
            password = "test",
            orgId = 1,    // This is the primary organization
            reportRequest = command
        };
        return rq;
    }
```

And I **[get](https://monosnap.com/image/gJKeHikG2FJWmupnBwmNJDxpjvEq6K.png) "An exception** of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll "
when creating

```
    new LegacyReportServiceService()
```

I've also tried to add it as a **Service Reference**, but the result is the same.

The **YF team sais** "We do have clients that are using .net and C# to develop their integration code. ...The support team has confirmed example code provided in development folder in the Yellowfin directory and WSDL code are accurate and are unable to replicate the errors you’ve identified in your original email."

Please help me to find out, what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that VS generates classes for the web service access from "localhost:8083/webservices/LegacyReportService?xsd=1" and it does that improperly. It makes String[] from original String type.

So editing the generated Reference.cs of the Web Reference did the thing.
At least, I've got the response with errorCode 25 "Not authorized".

Comment: I'm in exactly the same position as you :-) 
I also have the response code 25 after struggling with the mangled c# code.  I've no idea how to resolve the Error Code, have you made nay progress?

Comment: Update: I've added a forum post on the YellowFin site for this: http://www.yellowfinbi.com/YFForum-JAX-Service-ReportRequest-fails-with-Error-Code-25-?thread=179317

Comment: I've failed to get rid of code 25 with .Net so I tried java just to know if it works. A java console app with Web Service Client referencing the same service returned error code 0 and "SUCCESS" status. But it returned no data((. Maybe the reportId and tabId are incorrect. Do not know. Trying to extract them from YF DB now. If it works, I'll build a middle-layer service to convert YF data to a .Net-understandable format (JSON or like that) and to transfer it to my C# app.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to get rid of response code 25.

```
        rsr.orgId = 1;
        rsr.orgIdSpecified = true;
        rsr.dashboardTabId = 11111;
        rsr.dashboardTabIdSpecified = true;
        rsr.reportId = 22222;
        rsr.reportIdSpecified = true;
```

Certain parameters for yellowfin need to explicitly told to read.

Comment: This worked for me as well (thanks so much!). I came across this thread as well (https://community.yellowfinbi.com/topic/yf-authentication-error-error-code-25-from-net-code) but the solution around the serialization was unclear and after much tinkering this comment was the solution for me in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works

```
        reportServiceRequest rq = new reportServiceRequest();
        rq.loginId = "admin@xxxxx.com";
        rq.password = "xxxxxxx";
        rq.orgId = 1;
        rq.reportRequest = "RUNDASHBOARDREPORT";
        rq.reportId = reportId;
        rq.orgIdSpecified = true;
        rq.dashboardTabId = 11111;
        rq.dashboardTabIdSpecified = true;
        rq.reportIdSpecified = true;
        rq.dashboardTabId = tabId;

        using (var srv = new ServiceReference2.LegacyReportServiceClient())
        {
             YellowFinIntegrationWithDotNet.ServiceReference2.reportServiceResponse resp = null;
            try
            {
                resp = srv.remoteReportCall(rq); // there is no "remoteAdministrationCall" as in the doc
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                return resp;
            }


            return resp;
        }
```